# Map Google Drive to Network Drive or Local Drive

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I am attempting to connect to my Google Drive using C# and the Google Drive API and then map that as a network or local drive.  There are other programs I know that do this like [NetDrive](http://www.netdrive.net/) (which is extremely useful and robust), but I am looking to create something on my own.  I have created a project in the developer console and have been able to connect to Drive using my application and do various read and upload operations, so I know that particular portion is ok.  Access and permissions all seem to be set.  I just have no idea where to start when it comes to mapping that storage as a usable drive in Windows.  Any advice would be most helpful, thank you very much!

Comment: Haven't fully solved this quite yet, but I am looking into the Dokan libraries to try to accomplish this.  It has the capabilities, I just need to figure out how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

There are two basic components for implementing a NetDrive/WebDrive type of solution. What you are looking at is the creation of an Installable File System and Network Provider.

The Network Provider, or NP, is the user mode component that handles the Network layers, including the mapping and unmapping of the drive letter, along with lots of other fairly complicated UNC/Network stuff. To get an idea of what you are in for, check out the Win32 WNET*() API; you will need to implement all of the WNet() calls specifically for your IFS and 'network'.

When you are done, you'll probably have the ability to to do a "net use \MyWebDrive\" in DOS and Map Network Drive in Windows Explorer. You might also be able to use Windows Explorer to enum the contents of the remote file system.

However, now you need to make sure that all third party applications can access your network drive...to do that, you want to implement the Win32 File System API, such as CreateFile, Read(), Write(), CloseHandle(), FindFirst(), etc.

To do this, you can write an Installable File System Driver, FSD, to handle all I/O calls from User mode applications wanting to read/write to the files on that mapped network drive. This will most likely be a Kernel Mode application...a signed/certified file system device driver....probably written in old-school C and maybe even utilizing TDI depending on how you want to do your network IO.

Microsoft is becoming much more strict about installing 3rd party kernel mode drivers and network providers. The WebDrive file system driver is now securely signed using a Microsoft based TLS certificate and our Network Provider has been registered with the Microsoft Windows SDK team as a legitimate Network Provider for the Windows platform.

Once you get these pieces in place, you'll then want to think about Caching. Direct I/O through your NP/FSD over the wire to Google is not practical, so you'll need an intermediate caching system on your local drive. There are lots of ways to do that, too many to go into here. However, just keep in mind that you may have multiple user mode applications reading and writing to your network drive simultaneously (or one app like WinWord which opens multiple file handles), and you'll need to be able to handle all those requests with proper locking and ACLs, and then map those changes and access rules to the remote server.

Don't lose faith...what you are looking to do is possible as WebDrive and NetDrive have shown, but it's not really a project that can be knocked out in a few weekends. I'm not sure about the author of NetDrive, but we've been developing WebDrive full time since 1997. It seems that every Windows Patch changes something and every new version of Adobe/Office/XYZ does something quirky with IO calls that makes us pull our hair out.

Note: There's also another way to implement this beast which may get around the FSD, it's the DropBox strategy. Using a temporary folder on your local hard drive, leverage Directory Change Notifications in a User Mode application to monitor file changes in the folder and dynamically synchronize the changes to the remote end. GoogleDrive and a lot of the other online storage companies do it this way because it's quick-&-easy; however, if many changes occur in a short period, a Change Notification could get lost in Windows Messaging and data might get trashed.

I realize this is a lot to digest, but it's doable...it's cool stuff; good luck!

Comment: A lot to digest indeed, but very helpful and a really good high-level overview.  I really appreciate your response.  I'll probably have some follow-up questions at some point too.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that before you start coding, you take time to thoroughly understand Google Drive and map its capabilities to/from Windows. Some sample points of impedance:-

- folders in Drive aren't folders at all
- A file in Drive = the metadata, content is optional
- Drive has a lot of metadata that doesn't map to NTFS (eg. properties)
- Will applicable files be converted to Google Docs, or stored as is
- How will you map revisions
- Permissions

There are almost certainly more, this is just off the top of my head. Your app needs to make decisions regarding all of these aspects. Generally, Drive offers more capabilities than NTFS, so provided you are simply using it as a backup repository, you should be OK.

Comment: 100% agree, and I'm actually already in the processes of doing just that.  I  started my first tests with the authentication and basic file operations piece about week ago just to get a bit of a base and to get some experience with the dev console, and I've been studying up on the inner workings of drive and giving thoughts to what I can do and what I ultimately want to do.  Still have more to learn of course.  I do know that I'll want the drive map feature, so I wanted to start gathering advice sooner rather than later (so I don't stall out when it's time). Thank you for your advice!

Comment: actually, another couple of points to consider. 1/  mime-type. Drive uses mime-type in the same was Windows uses file extension. 2/ In Window, a file is identified by its path/filename; in Drive a file is identified by a unique ID, with the corollary that file-names can be duplicated.

Comment: Interesting - it almost seems more like working with database entries/objects than a traditional Windows file system.  That makes kind of clears up some things I was noticing when tinkering with the API.

Comment: Another discrepancy to consider is how you will deal with NTFS file shortcuts.